# Java Frameworks/Libraries to support creating "wizard-like" Commandline Applications

Tags: java, command-line, groovy, build

I need to create an interactive commandline application in Java and/or Groovy to orchestrate a very customized build and deployment process.

My current vision would be that the result should somehow feel like using a maven archetype: There will be a "wizard-like" workflow that prompts the user for input at several stages. Typically not all user-inputs are provided when starting the application (i.e: The user provides a subversion-url, then the applications queries subversion for all available tags and  displays them to the user and prompts the user to choose a tag for building...)

Are there any Java/Groovy libraries to support building such a commandline application?

So far I have found [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) and [Groovy CliBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/CliBuilder.html). But they seem not to be a help when it comes to "wizard-like" commandline applications, that query for user input at several points during runtime.

Any pointers would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a java package [jLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) which is used behind the scenes by groovysh. It supports custom tab-completion, saveable command history, and command line editing.

The best example of using it's features that I can find [is here](https://github.com/sandarenu/sample-apps/blob/master/java-cli-app/src/main/java/org/sansoft/samples/javacli/Shell.java), but there might be better examples elsewhere.

Hope this is what you were after?

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a bit more support regarding the "wizard-features". But probably that is too application specific to be handled in a framework/library ...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but maybe this will help someone else. [Spring Shell](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) is a tool that allows you to create interactive command line user interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I would give the Apache Commons Command Line Interface API a try. It's the same setup you see when you use something like Ant. I'm not sure about the wizard aspect you are looking for, but that could come from a loop you create, but then add in the code from the API to handle the inputs.

Here's a link to the Apache Commons [Command Line](http://commons.apache.org/cli/)

Comment: I think that the library that the Groovy CliBuilder wraps in a groovy-er interface

Comment: That wouldn't surprise me. I didn't know about the Apache one until I tried writing my own for a while.